# Prestashop availalibilty condition

Tags: if-statement, prestashop

Code part: http://pastebin.com/cC8jUkz8

```
<p style="line-height: 25px;" id="availability_statut"{if ($product->quantity <= 0 && !$product->available_later && $allow_oosp) OR ($product->quantity > 0 && !$product->available_now) OR !$product->available_for_order OR $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
<span id="availability_label">{l s='Availability:'}</span>
```

And how to write IF condition to get such result?

If product has available date it shows:

```
<span id="availability_date">{dateFormat date=$product->available_date full=false}</span>
```

Else if product dont have arrival date it show default delivery text like: 1-3 days or 2-4 weeks it shows:

```
<span id="availability_value"{if $product->quantity <= 0} class="warning_inline"{/if}>{if $product->quantity <= 0}{if $allow_oosp}{$product->available_later}{else}{l s='This product is no longer in stock'}{/if}{else}{$product->available_now}{/if}</span>
```

I tryed something like this:
{if $product->available_date != 0} SHOW date {else} Show default text {/if} but it not works. It shows date in good place, but dont show text anymore.

Now i can see like this: This product available in: 2-4 weeks (its available_later text)
and after this i can see: Coming in DATE

Answer (score 1):

I barely understood what exactly do you need, but you can check the available_date the following way:

```
{if $product->available_date != '0000-00-00'}

{/if}
```